# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello i am new to ROS and to Ubuntu !
I use ubuntu 12.04 and Ros Fuerte!I was trying to understant ROS through the examples of the book  "Learing Ros for Robotics Programming" but i've been stucked 2 days in creating nodes section !(pages 52-56)
I have made whatever it says but when i write  rosrun chapter2_tutorials example1_a on terminal i keep getting
"[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named example1_a below /home/ioannis/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials"
Is there any idea which the problem is?
If you want further info let me know!
Sorry for my bad english!
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200753/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named/) by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be that in your `CMakelists.txt` (see page 55 at the end of the page on the same book) you must define where your cpp files are in your system:

(from the book):

```
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a src/example1_a.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
```

for this reason be sure that the path and the name of the .cpp files are right.
if you didn't create a `src/` folder in your `chapter2_tutorials/` folder then you need to remove it from your `CMakelists.txt` file. For example it would be:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a example1_a.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_b example1_b.cpp)
```

I hope that this solve your problem. And don't forget to source your file in your terminal:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

EDIT: you picked up the only book that is made entirely from the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) online. For using and learning ROS I would suggest you to use the tutorials online since they are updated and much more detailed than the book. As an exercise can you lately switch to the book again and try to develop its robot's examples with the stuff you learned.

Ciao

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2015-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on 2015-01-11**:
First of all thank you for your time! unfortunately i have src folder and inside this folder is both example1 and example2 I think that the problem may be in bashrc file export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ioannis/dev/rosbook:/home/ioannis/dev/rosbook:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-11**:
did you initialize the workspace of ROS?!?!? In `~/dev/rosbook` you should initialize the workspace. Hydro and above need a `catkin_init`but since you are using Fuerte I'm not really sure

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-11**:
if I were you I would forget the book for a moment and start again slowly with the [tutorial online](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) Select rosbuild when asked for the system. I'm pretty sure you didn't initialize the workspace.

**Comment by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on 2015-01-11**:
So !should i prefer hydro?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-11**:
If you don't need Fuerte install Indigo!!
But if you are forced to use Fuerte you have to choose in the tutorials rosbuild.

If you can install Indigo

**Comment by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on 2015-01-11**:
ok!Thank you so much!

**Comment by [corilei](https://answers.ros.org/users/33288/corilei/) on 2018-01-15**:
rosrun chapter2_tutorials chap2_example1_a